# Iptables forward all traffic to a specified port, to another device

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

How can I modify this iptables rule, so that all traffic which coming for this computer will be forwarded to 192.168.42.10?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.46.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.42.10:80
```

The problem is that I create the ip tables rule from ansible and created it in different environments, where the ip address ranges are different, but I want to forward the 80 port to 192.168.42.10 always.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This rule will forward 80 port to 192.168.42.10

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.42.10:80
```

but this is not enough
If you want to get back traffic then you should add this rule

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.42.10 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.42.1
```

where ip address 192.168.42.1 is your iptables computer

These two rules have to solve the task.

Comment: Thank you it is working, but I had an other issue. Here is my current iptbales http://pastebin.com/gasEMiqh and it has a nat too to the LXC containers. When I use the port forward in the containers I cant use the yum, so I cant install packages. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have to configure yam to use  anHTTP proxy
To enable all yum operations to use a proxy server, specify the proxy server details in /etc/yum.conf. For additional information You can see this link https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-proxy-server.html

Comment: Is `net.ipv4.ip_forward` need to be enabled?

Comment: Thanks for this help. I was stuck. My problem was I was trying to route traffic to the ipTables computer over to an Arduino. The the above solution helped. my source and destination ports wer different. Here is what worked `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8081 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.158:80` and 
`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.158 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.178:8081`

Comment: This works. thanks. I spent many hours trying to make it work. and now it does. woohoo!