# forwarding a port to a hostname

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

How can one forward a port to a hostname and port. I was looking at this post: [Iptables forward all traffic to a specified port, to another device](https://serverfault.com/questions/765071/iptables-forward-all-traffic-to-a-specified-port-to-another-device) and see how to do it port to ip but what if I need to do port to hostname? Tried putting in a host as the destination but it throws in error in iptables

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination ehb-us-redis-001.ehb-usredis.u1.cache.com:6379
iptables v1.4.21: Bad IP address "ehb"

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Why not do the DNS lookup yourself and substitute in the IP for the hostname?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. The syntax is specified in the [iptables-extensions](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) man page as

```
--to-destination [ipaddr[-ipaddr]][:port[-port]]
```

While [`iptables`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) `-s` and `-d` syntax `address[/mask]` allows using hostnames, it's discouraged as it may cause security problems. As the `--to-destination` takes IP address ranges (for a simple round-robin load balancing), address syntax would be irrelevant.

> Hostnames will be resolved once only, before the rule is submitted to
>   the kernel. Please note that specifying any name to be resolved with a
>   remote query such as DNS is a really bad idea.

Furthermore, the Netfilter kernel module doesn't handle hostnames; if you think this would solve some problem with changing IP addresses, it won't.

If you really need to use hostnames, a *reverse proxy* would be more applicable.

Comment: ok...this makes sense on why you shouldn't do this...