# How to forward all incoming packets to certain ip?

Tags: networking, iptables

I want to forward all tcp packets incoming to my PC`s `7778` port to the connected device. It's ip - `192.168.137.111`. Nmap shows that it listens for `7778` port and I can ping it from my PC. According to [this](https://serverfault.com/a/765539/516465) answer, I've added the following rules:
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 7778 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.137.111:7778`
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.137.111 --dport 7778 -j SNAT --to-source 10.99.220.62`
Where `10.99.220.62` is my PC`s ip.

Also, I've added `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7778 -j ACCEPT`
Then, when I'm trying to connect to `10.99.220.62:7778` from another computer, `tcpdump -i enp3s0 'port 7778'` shows one packet: `19:56:08.035819 IP 10.99.221.104.60827 > alexandr-All-Series.7778: Flags [S], seq 568409282, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0` 
 But when I'm trying to tcpdump `enx006037a1f5ef` that "stands" for the connected device, it shows nothhing. And I don't get any response on the computer that has sent the packet.
I'm using Mint 19

Comment: Could you include the output of `iptables -L  -v --line-numbers` and `iptables -L -t nat -v --line-numbers` ?

Comment: @JoseRaulBarreras https://pastebin.com/cD8DbBKt https://pastebin.com/Z9MkFsdE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your firewall `FORWARD` chain policy is set to DROP, and there is no other rule for accepting packets for your port. This means that the firewall will drop the packet when it is becoming to the router.

You need to add the following rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.137.111 -p tcp --dport 7778 -j ACCEPT
```